# Initializing repository with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

[image attached after answer from Lorelorelore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUgdv.jpg)

basically, I tried to use hibernate in my project, but it became pretty chaotic, so I decided to test it again, so I created a new spring project. I have a POJO - Car class and a CarRepository. As far as I understand, it should use basic methods from the CRUD repository - but, when I want to save a object (or use any other method) it just doesn't work (it shows that I should initialize variable "carRepository"). Could you please help me with that? Thanks in advance

```
//CARTESTER CLASS

public class CarTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @Autowired
        CarRepository carRepository;
//I want to use a method from crudrepository here
        carRepository.save(new Car(1, "AAA", "BBB", 1111));
        carRepository.findAll();
    }
}

//CAR CLASS
@Table(name = "CARS")
@Entity
    public class Car {

        @Id
        private Integer id;
        private String brand;
        private String model;
        private int manufactureYear;
//constructors, getters, setters, toString()

//CARREPOSITORY CLASS
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Integer> {


}
```

Comment: FWIW A XXXRepository is NOTHING to do with the JPA API. It is Spring Data

Answer (score 0):

Your test class should look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJPATest
public class CarTester {

 @Autowired
 CarRepository carRepository;

 @Test
 public void test() {
    carRepository.save(new Car(1, "AAA", "BBB", 1111));
    carRepository.findAll();
 }
}
```

Comment: This error still occurs (I just added a screen in my first post). Thanks however, you remind me, that I'll have to look into junit again.

Comment: Please add the error details as text and not as image, in this way more people could help you.

Comment: I make a mistake in my answer, now it has been edited. Can you check if it works @Vas?

Comment: it doesn't show, that I should initialize a variable "carRepository" anymore, it doesn't run correctly however showing :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.